# How I can implement dynamic FAQ in ASP.Net using C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

How I can implement dynamic FAQ in `ASP.Net` using `C#`?
`QuestionList` is a protected list in code behind.

I want to set `href` in `a` tag and `id` in `div` tag programmaticaly.

This is my code for adding all of it but the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m0RY.jpg) of each `panel` is still empty.

```
<%foreach (var v in QuestionList)
  { %>
<!-- /.panel -->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="'collapse'+'<%# Eval("v.Id") %>'" >
                <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("v.Question")%>'></asp:Label>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="'collapse'+'<%# Eval("v.Id") %>'" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("v.Answer")%>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<%} %>
```

Comment: How does it "does not work"? What should it do? What are the errors? Compile/runtime? Please provide a lot more information.

Comment: The result is some empty div . My question and answer does not show .

Comment: I would start troubleshooting this by evaluating the count of items in QuestionList. You would be surprised how often this is because of an empty list.

Comment: QuestionList have 10 items . I fill it first in code behind .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `#` and delete `+` on your `href` :

```
`<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%# Eval("v.Id") %>" >
```

'>
   
`

And do the same thing on the `div` class :

```
`<div id="collapse<%# Eval("v.Id") %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("v.Answer")%>'></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>`
```

And last, i have a suggestion, why didn't you use `repeater` instead of `foreach`?

Comment: Great to help @Nader :)